# How do you use Angular JS to read multiple properties and values from a settings file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a bit new to Angular JS, and was hoping to figure out how to use an external settings file in conjunction with my app. Currently, I have my code running in a way that allows me to import my settings.js file.

```
var settings = {

    options : {
        foo : "video",
        bar : .8
    }

    colors : {
        top : "#FF0000",
        bottom : "FF00FF"
    }
}
```

My issue, is that my settings file will have a lot of different properties and values. As is, my code has me write out line by line the settings that I'd like to use.  In the example, this will be `foo` and `bar`. How can I go about avoiding this?

Instead of having multiple lines of code, what logic could I use to simply allow me to read all the properties and values of my object?

You can see this in the example where I want to use `settings.colors.accentColor` and `settings.colors.frameColor`.  My settings.js file might contain hundreds of different options, and I'll definitely have other categories of options (not just options and colors).

```
<div ng-app="settingsApp" ng-controller="settingsCtrl">
    <script src="Settings/settings.js"></script>

    <h1>Use video: {{ foo }}</h1>
    <h2>Colors</h2>
    <p>Background : {{ bar }}</p>
    <p>Accent : {{ settings.colors.accentColor }}</p>
    <p>Colors : {{ settings.colors.frameColor }}</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var app = angular.module('settingsApp', []);
    app.controller('settingsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.foo = settings.options.foo;
      $scope.bar = settings.colors.backgroundOverlay;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in that manner, try to load the file as json data directly. Here's is a good link where I learned how to use angularjs. Of course there are plenty other good ones too, but it's a matter of personal opinions and stuff. This guy also has tutorial video explaining each examples in the below link.

The example #20 is the one that may help you with your task

https://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a lot more simple than I thought - thanks to help from a friend I figure out this solution.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('settingsApp', []);
        app.controller('settingsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.settings = settings;
        });
</script>
```

Simply put, I just attached the scope to the settings object I imported.